# android context nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a little issue with android Context and I don't know how to solve the problem.Here is the code I am using :

```
public class TestActivity {
Context context;
public static  String getPackageVersion(){  
        try {
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            version = packageInfo.versionName;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return version;
    }

    public static boolean checkClientApiVer(String clientApiVer){

        int s = RPCCommunicator.strVerToIntVer(clientApiVer);
        int c = RPCCommunicator.strVerToIntVer(getPackageVersion());

        return (c>=s);
    }

     public boolean execute() {

        serverApiVer = jsonObj.getString("server_api_ver");
        Log.w("SERVER API VER","SHOW SERVER API VERSION : "+serverApiVer);

            checkClientApiVer(serverApiVer);
}
```

}

and it says Nullpointer exception in this line :

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
```

Actually I can't use `this.getPackageManager()`, or `TestActivity.getPackageManager()` and I can't set `context` to `this`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you figured this out ? Just got the same behaviour. (Answers are surprisingly useless)

Answer (score 3):

@Roflcoptr pointed out the basic, but actually, your class doesn't extend activity, so it is not a context, change it to:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
```

if you want it to be an actual activity, or, if it should be only a helper class, pass it the activity when it is instantiated.

Comment: Actually I forget to mention and add that my TestActivity already extends a custom class.And it's just a helper class, not an Activity

Comment: if your class is not an Activity , then you should pass the context to the your class in the constructor as i describe in my answer

Comment: Actually it still doesn't help

Answer (score 3):

If your class is an activity, it's better to use this as a context. If you need a context in another class, you can have a singleton pointer on your applicationContext.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static MyApp instance;

    public MyApp() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and in your manifest file :

```
<application
    android:name="com.mycompany.appname.MyApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Now you can always have a context with

```
MyApp.GetContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you declared context but never instantiated or assigned a reference to it. So it points to null.

Normally you TestActivity should be a subclass from the Activity class or something similar.

In this case you could do something like

```
this.getPackageManager();
```

Answer (score 2):

you should to initialize your context by adding a constructor  of your class which is not an Activity ,

```
public TestActivity(Context c) {
   this.context = c;
}
```

and in your Activity , instantiate the `TestActivity` by sending `this` as a parameter like this :

```
TestActivity tActivity = new TestActivity(this);//this refer to the Activity
```

The second solution is by extending an Activity , and you should **override** the method `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating context object in class and keeping reference of activity or application lead to memory leaks in android bcz you are not  creating any object of particular class.

you can achieve this by doing below steps

1> create singleton class of application context and define application class in manifest.xml ; so their will be one context object in entire application life cycle

2> pass context when ever you are using that method.

```
public static  String getPackageVersion(Context context){  
    try {
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        version = packageInfo.versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return version;
}
```